# Message: Invalid character Internet Explorer

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug an application that has all of the sudden stopped working and get the errors below. When I run the app via Google Chrome everything works but when it runs in Internet Explorer it does not work. Application has been in production for a long time and it just started not working I dont know what could cause these errors in Internet Explorer and how could they be debugged?

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET      CLR 3.5.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 27 Jul 2012 15:11:31 UTC

Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://web-davw01/ApTrac/AddContact.aspx


Message: Invalid character
Line: 1
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://web-davw01/ApTrac/AddContact.aspx
```

Comment: What is the character at position 2 line 1?

Comment: As @asawyer said...  has someone opened the project, done something dumb, and then saved it?

Comment: @asawyer yeah it is at Line: 1 Char: 2

Comment: @Moo-Juice No, no one has opened the project that I know off the dates of last modified were long time time ago.

Comment: Nick, again, What is the character at position 2 line 1?

Comment: I am sorry @asawyer where would I be able to find the character at that position would it say inside internet explorer or do I look inside code?

Comment: It's an aspx page. They typically start with `<%`. So the 2nd character is `%`. Am I right? What do you see when you view source in IE?

Comment: @AnthonyFaull That's what I was trying to get at. I think your answer is probably correct.

Comment: It is % that is correct.

Comment: When you view source in Chrome do you also see the `<%`?

Comment: Try clearing Chrome's cache. And try copying IE's url into a new Chrome window. Does the same thing happen?

Comment: @AnthonyFaull yes it does. It still works in chrome but now in IE. I found this link http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/troubleshoot.asp but I dont completely understand if this would help under section . Problem: Overlong headers result in HTTP/4xx or HTTP/5xx errors, particularly on devices like routers or webcams

Answer (score 1):

You need to [register ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on your IIS web server:

1. Run `CMD.exe`.
2. Change directory to the latest version of the .NET framework. e.g. `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`
3. Run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`